# How to avoid quotes around strings in variables with a custom format in the display inside Datasets in V11?

Tags: dataset, format

I'm wondering how to deal with some unwanted behaviour of the new display format of `Dataset` in Mathematica 11 (I'm using version 11.0.1):

I'm using a custom "type", in this example `MyType` for which I define the output format:

```
MakeBoxes[mt : MyType[a_, b_], StandardForm] ^:= 
  Row[{a, "-xx-", b}] // ToBoxes;
```

This works fine in the standard output, e.g. evaluating `MyType[1, 2]` gives

```
1-xx-2
```

as output. However, when I evaluate it inside a dataset as `Dataset[MyType[1, 5]]`, the output is

```
1"-xx-"5
```

This behavior is new in version 11 - in version 10.4, this worked fine and no quotes were added around the string. This problem also doesn't occur when I manually put a string inside a `Dataset`: `Dataset[Row[{1, "--", 5}]]` gives

```
1-xx-2
```

which is the way I want it to be displayed.

Using `Format` instead of `MakeBoxes`doesn't help. Is there a better way to define a custom output format in v11, or is this a bug?

Comment: What happens if you use `MakeBoxes[mt : MyType[a_, b_], StandardForm] ^:= 
  Style[Row[{a, "-xx-", b}], ShowStringCharacters -> False] // ToBoxes;` ? (I am using version 10.1.0 so I cannot test this.)

Comment: This works - thanks a lot!